# Implementation restriction:'FILE READONLY' Can not directly access remote package variable or cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracleforms

I am trying to insert pdf file into oracle database using `form 6i`. Here is the code I have written.

```
DECLARE
l_blob  BLOB;
l_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME ('D:\pdf\', 'a.pdf');
begin
insert into demo values (1, EMPTY_BLOB())
returning theblob into l_blob;
dbms_lob.fileopen (l_bfile)
dbms_lob.loadfromfile (l_blob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength (l_bfile));
dbms_lob.fileclose (l_bfile);
END;
```

This code works well when I execute them in `Toad 9.0.1.8`. While using this in `oracle form 6i`, It shows the error,

> Implementation restriction:'FILE READONLY' Can not directly access remote package variable or cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got rid of this problem but not by forms 6i. Created a `procedure`in the back end and just called it in `forms 6i` .Thats it ! Here is the procedure which can save my pdf file into BLOB column.....

```
create or replace procedure save_blob
as
  l_blob  BLOB;
  l_bfile BFILE := BFILENAME ('MY_PDF', 'a.pdf');
begin
  insert into demo values (4, EMPTY_BLOB())
  returning theblob into l_blob;
  dbms_lob.fileopen (l_bfile);
  dbms_lob.loadfromfile (l_blob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength (l_bfile));
  dbms_lob.fileclose (l_bfile);
 COMMIT;
end;
```

'MY_PDF ' is the directory created by the command

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY my_pdf AS 'D:\pdf\';
```